# Cardinality Confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-modeling, cardinality

I am creating a database and I have a bit of a confusion with a cardinality. The situation is that there is a couple and they receive award(money) but the award is split into two, 40/60 so the husband gets 40% and the wife gets 60%. Is this a 1 to Many or a Many to Many? So I am being sent the award from another table, should it be M:M or 1:M?

1 split award can have many claimants?

or

Many split awards can have many claimants?

Comment: What about **couple** is it a single record or two records?

Comment: 2 records, 1 record for husband and 1 record for wife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is a little vague, but my impression is that you have three key entities:

- Awards
- GroupOfPersons
- Persons

An award goes to a group of people.  So, the relationship between an "award" and a "group of persons" is 1-many (one award goes to only one group, one group could get many awards).

Then, you need to allocation the award among the people, so you have a relationship between each "group of persons" and a person.  This would include percentage allocation information for the award.

Your description is not clear as to whether this is 1-many or many-to-many or 1-many-at-a-atime.  That is, can a person be in more than one group?  If by "couple" you mean "married couple", then it sounds like 1-many, but people do get divorced an re-married, so it might be 1-many but only at a given time.